# Associating ForeignKey on auth.User model

Tags: django, django-models, models

I'm trying to associate an `Account` model with the standard django `auth.User` model.

The way I see it happening is to have a `ForeignKey` on `User`, pointing to `Account`, so I can use something like `account.users`.

Like so

```
class User(User):
    account = ForeignKey(Account, related_name='users')
    ...
```

However, as we all know, the recommended way to add information to the `User` model is via a `UserProfile`.

Like so

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    account = ForeignKey(Account, related_name='profiles')
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

which means that if I want to get a list of all `Users` in an `Account`, account, I need to do something like,

```
users = [p.user for p in account.profiles]
```

While this is only one line, I'm assuming that every `p.user` generates an additional database hit, which seems highly inefficient, as compared to if the `User` model were accessible through the `Account` model directly.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to achieve and yes, my answer would have limited you to a single Account per User. I misread, sorry, have removed my answer for the time being until I can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right you want all the User of a specific account. Given that, you should be able to do the following, or something similar.

```
users = User.objects.filter(userprofile__account=account)
```

Comment: Yes, this would actually work, albeit in a slightly roundabout manner, and requiring a slight context switch. 

Well, to me anyway. 

(And this would require an additional JOIN, but I can live with that =)

Comment: This would require an additional JOIN? This would result in one JOIN - User JOIN UserProfile. In any case I'm glad you found this answer useful.

Comment: One "additional" JOIN as compared to if the `account` field were stored directly on `User` I suppose, but it works for me, thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the additional db lookups per profile by using the `select_related`.

```
profiles = account.select_related().profiles
```

will also include all user lookups within the only query.

Here is the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: Unfortunately, `select_related()` only seems to work in the reverse direction for `OneToOneField`s and not `ForeignKey`s. So while I could use `select_related()` when querying `UserProfile`s to retrieve `Account`s (since `UserProfile` defines the `ForeignKey` to `Account`), I couldn't do it from `Account`